# Centos 7 : No space left on device after growing partition

Tags: ssh, hard-drive, samba, centos7

That makes two weeks that I have a problem with a **CentOS 7** development server.
I did several internet searches but no information has helped me.
All persons with the same error message that I have managed to solve their problem.

I enlarged the primary partition of **50GB** and I rebooted the server. For 3 days, there was no problem. I could access it by *SSH* and *Samba*. And overnight, he bugged and no longer works. I have only access to the console and nothing else.

By searching the Internet, I tried several commands:

- [df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plTdj.png)
- [df -ih](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNC2q.png)
- du -h --max-depth=1 --exclude=mnt
- mount -o remount,inode64 /

And plenty of other commands (I do not remember) ...

I don't know what to do. Can someone help me ? I have already searched a lot on Google but nothing works for me.

Thank you !

- HD : 50GB to 100GB
- OS : CentOS 7
- FileSystem : xfs

----- RESOLVED

I solved the problem. Samba had files that do not have the correct Unix rights. They were in 0755 and I put them in 0700 ...

(Take a look to the logs files)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I speak french and English isn't my primary language ... :D

Comment: What type is your root filesystem? xfs/ext2/ext3/ext4? How did you expand the filesystem? Show the exact commands if possible.

Comment: _root@php /> mount_ : /dev/mapper/centos-root on / type **xfs** (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)

Comment: This **sounds** like the old issue with full XFS filesystems being extended (as mentioned in the XFS FAQ http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ and at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306328/xfs-file-system-lack-of-space) **but** that should only matter for filesystems bigger than 1TB (and anyway mounting with inode64 option should fix it). In no-one's got any other suggestions moving some older files off temporarily to free space at the start of the filesystem might be worth a try.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you. I already saw the second link but I will try with the first (xfs.org).

Comment: Since this is solved, can you please copy that paragraph (with some details if you deign so) to an answer and accept it? Otherwise, the system will keep pushing this around and prioritizing as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Samba had files that do not have the correct Unix rights. They were in 0755 and I put them in 0700 ...

(Take a look to the logs files)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/526524)